# Find unique number in Integer array/list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given an integer array/list(ARR) of size N. Where N is equal to [2M + 1].
Now, in the given array/list, 'M' numbers are present twice and one number is present only once.
Find and return that number that is unique in the array/list.

Note: Unique element is always present in the array/list according to the given condition.

I have done this question using WHILE loop, but when I am trying to do this using FOR loop it is not working

and, I have seen some codes for this type of problem, but as I am a learner and have done only some basic python so and don't know yet about the COMPLEXITY(O^N).

please help and thanks in advance

WHILE loop code:

```
def find_unique(li,n):
    for i in range(n):
        j = 0
        while(j < n):
            if i != j:
                if li[i] == li[j]:
                    break
            j = j + 1
        if j == n:
            return li[i]
n = 7
li = [2,3,1,6,3,6,2]
ele = find_unique(li,n)
print(ele)
```

FOR loop code:

```
def find_unique(li,n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0,n):
            if i == j:
                continue
            if(li[i] == li[j] and j ==n):
                    return li[i]
        

n = 7
li = [2,3,1,6,3,6,2]
ele = find_unique(li,n)
print(ele)
```

Comment: convert to numpy.ndarray or a pandas dataframe . They both have a function for it. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html  and https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html .  You can look at some examples in the documentation. Python is slow in for loops, so, whenever you can, convert to numpy array and use the functions of that as they're quite fast. It's called vectorization if you want to read more about it.

Comment: In the for-loop, will `j` ever reach `n`?

Comment: What purpose does the j==n serve exactly?

Comment: @SinaMeftah it is not relevant to the question as the author wants to find the issue in code.

Comment: @DeepakGouda yes, i know j is not reaching n . but, how to correct it.

Comment: @DeepakGouda Beause he asked about complexity I've suggested a better way to do this. As there is a `return_count` argument in the `numpy.unique() ` function too. Yes he's suggested some code, but my take was maybe he's looking for a way to solve his problem efficiently. Sometimes one can't see outside the box because they're new to an area of knowledge

Answer (score 3):

```
def unique(arr,N):
    ans=0
    for i in range(N):
        ans=ans^arr[i]
    return ans
```

Comment: I like this answer - I knew there had to be a mathematical way to do this. (BTW you can simplify this by iterating over the list directly. "for n in arr: ans = ans ^ n")

Comment: I have to say this idea is great, but it doesn't seem to be all that satisfying. For example, `[2, 3, 6, 3, 6, 2, 3, 11]`.

Comment: @pppig your test case is fine but in the question it is already provided every numbers are present in pairs and there is only one unique value, but in your case 3 is present 3 times which is violating the problem statement . Hope I was able to answer your query.

Comment: @AdityaVikram Oh, you are right, after reading your answer, I can not help but want to understand its thinking, so that I forget the description of the question, this idea is really great.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced some code

```
def find_unique(li,n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0,n):
            if i != j:
                if li[i] == li[j]:
                    break
            j = j + 1
        if j == n:
            return li[i]
n = 7
li = [2,3,1,6,3,6,2]
ele = find_unique(li,n)
print(ele)
```

Comment: thanks, for the answer. i just want to know why there is  j = j + 1, if that is being done by the for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

li = [2, 3, 1, 6, 3, 6, 2]
print([key for key, val in Counter(li).items() if val == 1])

# [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
def find_unique(li,n):
    a = Counter(li).most_common()
    return a[len(a)-1][0]    
n = 7
li = [2,3,1,6,3,6,2]
ele = find_unique(li,n)
print(ele)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a very specific case - with all items repeating twice but one. You can pull off a simple one-liner using this property

```py
find_unique = lambda li, n: 2*sum(set(li)) - sum(li)
```

Once you have defined the function - Now use it

```py
n = 7
li = [2,3,1,6,3,6,2]
ele = find_unique(li, n)
print(ele)
```

Answer (score 0):

JAVA CODE:

public class Solution{

```
public static int findUnique(int[] arr){
    
    int n = arr.length;
    int similar = arr[0]; //first element of array is stored as similar
    //now compare similar with every element of array
    for(int i=1; i<=n-1; i++)
    {
        similar = similar ^ arr[i];
        //XOR operation 1^1 || 0 ^0 = 0
        //XOR operation 1^0 || 0^1= 1
        
        //therefore, similar ^ similar = 0
        //similar ^ unique  = unique
        //similar takes the value of unique after XOR
    }
    
    return similar; //unique element is returned using similar named variable
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
def find_unique(li,n):
    unique_numbers = list(set(li))
    for i in unique_numbers:
        if li.count(i) == 1:
            return i
    return "No number once"
```

It return the number that is once in the array. Size N is not necessary.
Set and Count are functions from list variables. Set return unique elements in the array and count return the number of times an element is in the array.

Answer (score 0):

From an array, to find unique values with its count; just use np.unique function as follows:

```
unique_values = np.unique(any_2d_array.flatten(), return_counts=True)
```

For example after counting an image (of mask), I got the result. That means the array contains 3 unique values 1, 2, 3 and these appears 22938, 198766 and 18296 times, respectively.[image]

To get count into a separate variable, you can use like this:

```
unique_values, count = np.unique(any_2d_array.flatten(), return_counts=True)
```